# Error when adding buildFeatures in build.gradle file

Tags: android, user-interface, androidx, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying out compose which is a new feature in Andorid jetpack. Below is my code. I am adding buildfeatures in build.gradle file of app, not in the root folder.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion compileSDKVer
    buildToolsVersion buildToolsVer
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.slothyhacker.jetpackcompose"
        minSdkVersion minSdkVer
        targetSdkVersion targetSdkVer
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
        //compose true
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Set both the Java and Kotlin compilers to target Java 8.
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

But my project is giving me a compile error. I would really appreciate if someone can put some light on what am doing wrong.

```
Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [build_7yf57wk394cperk1t82v120yf$_run_closure1$_closure5@78c292be] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
```

Comment: what is your Gradle version?

Comment: What is the minimum api level ? and it should be 21 or higher

Comment: You can add this only in Android Studio 4.0+ which is only available Canary build

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this only in Android Studio 4.0+ which is only available Canary build

Comment: I don't think this is an exact answer. This error repeats when I have version 4.0.1

Comment: Do you know canary build of version 4.0.1 @Mr.Lemon

Comment: I'm using 4.1 RC3 but still

Comment: Mine is 4.1 but this is still happening.

Comment: Its working fine for me at v4.1.1 Android Studio after the upgrade.

Comment: I am on version 4.1.1 but it is still giving me error

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh is error is same as described in question?

Comment: I'm still getting the error with this version of Android Studio 4.0.1 any more help on this issue

Comment: on the latest canary version, still getting this error

Answer (score 43):

I caught this error when I tried to add Jetpack to my existing app. I followed [Suraj's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692811/error-when-adding-buildfeatures-in-build-gradle-file) answer, even used the newest *Kotlin* gradle plugin, and couldn't exactly figure out what was wrong. I also followed the official [setup guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup) and it didn't work. Everything *seemed* okay, but nothing helped.

Installing Android Studio 4.0 canary didn't help either.

Turns out, it's not enough to just include certain dependencies – you need specific versions or higher. I was using an older **Android** Gradle plugin: `3.5.3`. Upgrading to `4.0.0-alpha07` fixed the error:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha07'
```

Make sure to check your dependencies if you're adding Jetpack to an existing app

Comment: I'm told to never upgrade the Gradle and every time I do I have to re-install everything again!

Answer (score 43):

It seems that this

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

Is replaced with

```
viewBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/ViewBindingSample/app/build.gradle)

Comment: You are right, no idea why you have been downvoted. Also the google documentation is wrong. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: Wrong. Even the link from Marvin Effing  says: "    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }"

Answer (score 14):

For `build.gradle.kts` I **wasn't able** to add it with

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

What **worked** was this:

```
android {
    buildFeatures.dataBinding = true
    buildFeatures.viewBinding = true
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To add jetpack compose to your project, you need to follow below steps:

**Note: You should be on 4.1 Canary build of Android Studio**

Step 1 :  Inside the `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildFeatures {
        // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
        compose true
    }
    ...

    // Set both the Java and Kotlin compilers to target Java 8.

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Note: Jetpack Compose currently requires an experimental version of the Kotlin-Gradle plugin. To include this plugin in your app, include the following in your project’s build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // To download the required version of the Kotlin-Gradle plugin,
        // add the following repository.
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.60-eap-25'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Add Jetpack Compose toolkit dependencies in your `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    // You also need to include the following Compose toolkit dependencies.
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev02'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev02'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev02'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah! It's works. Thank you and I want to know where did you find that code?
I didn't find that in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#add-compose)

Answer (score 6):

> it depends on which version of Android Studio (and gradle) you're using. The above syntax is used for the newer versions of gradle (Android Studio 4.0 canary and above)

If you're using 3.5.3, please use the following:

```
dataBinding {
   enabled = true
 }
```

source: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-android/issues/90

Comment: This also worked with Android Studio 3.6.3. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try to up you dependencies
yourproject/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    }
}
```

And
yourproject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved for me by upgrading to Android Studio 4.1.2 and Gradle to the 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

this will resolve using Android 4.0 and above version.

if still not work then please try to set data binding

replace

```
android {
       buildFeatures {
           dataBinding = true
       }
   }
```

by this

```
    android {
            buildFeatures.dataBinding = true
   }
```

it is worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem when replacing Kotlin synthetics with `viewBinding`. Turned out I had placed the `buildFeatures` in the wrong part of the gradle file. I accidentally put it outside the `android` section, which is where I previously had the experimental flag set for `androidExtensions`.

So I had to take this:

```
android {
  ...
}

buildFeatures {
  viewBinding = true
}
```

And cange it to this:

```
android {
  ...

  buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the Top level build.gradle file Gradle version to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'` and distributionUrl in Gradle-wrapper.properties as `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip` . This helped me get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

It must be wrong build.gradle file in which you adding this. If you see, there are two files, we have to select build.gradle (Module: <project_name.app>), which is named as build.gradle (:app) when you open it.

Answer (score 0):

My Android Studio is of 3.2.1 version , and below code worked for me. Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle file, in the android section, add the following lines:

```
   dataBinding {
      enabled = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to the latest build at https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

Answer (score 0):

Latest, Just change version of gradle in top-level(project-level) build.gradle file to latest,

```
     buildscript {
        repositories {
            // Gradle 4.1 and higher include support for Google's Maven repo using
            // the google() method. And you need to include this repo to download
            // Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
            google()
            ...
        }
        dependencies {
//Update This Line with latest Gradle version
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        }
    }
```

check latest gradle [version here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#groovy)

Answer (score 0):

Changing gradle version worked for me

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.3"
```

to

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
```