# Add Jetpack Compose to my existing project

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am getting this error after adding

```
buildFeatures {
        // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
        compose true
    }
```

in buid.gradle file.

**Error :** 
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [build_54unkt2ry74bgjccfbal5enyq$_run_closure1$_closure10@24191eaa] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

Comment: You can add this only in Android Studio 4.0+ which is only available Canary build

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when adding buildFeatures in build.gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692811/error-when-adding-buildfeatures-in-build-gradle-file)

Answer (score 0):

In App **Gradle** file

```
buildFeatures {
    // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
    compose true
}
```

Make sure you are using

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Add under dependencies in app "gradle file"

```
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev02'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev02'
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev02'
```

Courtesy [Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup)

After setup, you can successfully use this. Thanks

Comment: same error after adding this code @Haseeb Mirza

Comment: What is Android Studio version ? is it  Android Studio Canary ? https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

Comment: Android Studio  4.0 Beta 1