# Gradle "setMinSdk()" and others is marked as unstable with @incubating in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

After upgrading android studio to 2022.1.1 many of my grade functions were marked with this warning:

[image]

How should I resolve warnings?

Answer (score 3):

So from what others have written about this, this seems to be only a hint that it might change at one time in the future. Right now this seems to be still fine.

Basically it means **you should keep your eyes open for changes in future versions** since someone is working on making this better.
If it really bothers you, *Krystian Kaniowski* mentioned in his answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63915888/1565635

that you can suppress it for now via

```
@Suppress("UnstableApiUsage")
```

Comment: As far as I remembered, during these years of building apps, always the Gradle returned warnings and said we are using an obsolete function