# Error after adding buildFeatures in build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

After i added the **buildFeatures { viewBinding = true }** setting in my build.gradle file, i got this error:

`Gradle sync failed: Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [build_7orzo6phc1edx9en9cbbvrw3q$_run_closure1$_closure3@23aed4b2] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.`

I have recently updated my studio to version 4, but the error seems to persist.

Any idea how i can fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knncD.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when adding buildFeatures in build.gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692811/error-when-adding-buildfeatures-in-build-gradle-file)