# android studio ( kotlin ) build.gradle error?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

```
Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [build_5qfbvnnecz3eqc49l2rxxrlkt$_run_closure1$_closure6@1dd6d6e6] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.
```

I am getting an error like this can you help me? Here is the [screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIryT.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692811/error-when-adding-buildfeatures-in-build-gradle-file please check here

Comment: what is line 33 of the build file?